# Storyboard: 'Subclasses of UIStoryboardSegue must override -perform.'

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, uistoryboardsegue

I just want to create custom segue so i have written below code. The code is seems fine but when i run this code it is giving below error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Subclasses of
>   UIStoryboardSegue must override -perform.'

Below is the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Temp-2.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 Temp_2 *toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Temp2"];
 segue1=[[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"temp" source:self destination:toViewController];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionPush:(id)sender {

 [self prepareForSegue:segue1 sender:sender];
 [segue1 perform];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([segue1.identifier isEqualToString:@"temp"])
 {
     [segue1.destinationViewController setStr:@"string passed"];

 }
}
 @end
```

Any one please help me, What is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. For creating custom segue like above, We require to subclass UIStoryBoardSegue class and override the method perform. Below is the code that i have implemented.

```
#import "MyCustomSegue.h"

@implementation MyCustomSegue
- (void)perform
{
UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *destination = self.destinationViewController;

UIWindow *window = source.view.window;

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setDuration:1.0];
[transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[transition setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[transition setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];


[window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[window setRootViewController:destination];
}
```

This code will create the Push type animation and also solve above error.